# Getting specific counts in Mysql using case / if

Tags: mysql

I am trying to device an incentive plan for my sales agents depending on number of orders, and which shift they worked in.

The `sales` table (mysql) has the following columns:

```
sale_id (int, primary, auto increment)
employee (varchar, 255)
sale_time (datetime, the time sale was placed)
sale_amount (float 10,2)
sales_channel (tinyint, with values call (1), walk_in (2),referral(3))
is_cancelled (tinyint, with values 1 for cancelled, and 0 as default)
(and a few other columns that are not relevant for this case)
```

I want to have write a query to fetch result with following columns (I use orders and sales interchangeably):

```
employee
total_orders (count excluding cancelled sales, i.e. is_cancelled!= 1)
orders_below_100dollars (orders count with sale_amount below 100 and is_cancelled = 0)
orders_above_100dollars (orders count with sale_amount above 100 and is_cancelled = 0)
orders_dayShift (orders count placed between 9am and before 10pm and is_cancelled = 0)
orders_nightShift (orders count placed after 10pm and before next day 9am and is_cancelled = 0)
cancelled_orders (orders count with is_cancelled = 1)
```

I understand that the query would have `group by`, `case` and perhaps `if/else` in the select, but can't frame it properly. Please help.

Comment: You did not precise if total_orders and orders_below, etc. should contain number of orders in each category or the amount totals.

Comment: Will edit thanks. I meant the count.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use conditional aggregation for a lot of these. In other words, put the condition inside of a `SUM()` function to get the count of rows matching certain conditions:

```
SELECT employee, 
   SUM(is_cancelled <> 1) AS totalOrders, 
   SUM(sale_amount < 100 AND is_cancelled <> 1) AS orders_below_100,
   SUM(sale_amount > 10 AND is_cancelled <> 1) AS orders_above_100,
   SUM(sale_time < '22:00:00' AND is_cancelled <> 1) AS orders_dayshift,
   SUM(sale_time > '22:00:00' AND is_cancelled <> 1) AS orders_nightshift,
   SUM(is_cancelled = 1) AS totalCanceled
FROM sales
GROUP BY employee;
```

Comment: @jpw I didn't know this was non-standard, it was a strategy I picked up from SO. I will do some research on the topic and edit my answer when I have more relevant info. Thanks!

Comment: thanks, I'll try this. instead of order_time it's sale_time

Comment: @SantoshAchari sorry for that. I'm also not sure what type you store sale_time as, so I'm not sure what the condition is for you, but I trust you can at least figure out that part.

Comment: thanks for that!. @McAdam331

Also just as question, would this work:

Comment: SUM(sale_time > '09:00:00' and sale_time < '22:00:00' AND is_cancelled <> 1) AS orders_dayshift,

Comment: @SantoshAchari it should work. The only thing to keep in mind is that if they're stored as `datetime` types, you need to ensure you're only comparing the time fields. As long as you're comparing the right values, the syntax is fine for that to get say `num_orders_midday` or whatever you use.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/83797/discussion-between-santosh-achari-and-mcadam331).

Answer (score 3):

You are looking to use conditional aggregation -- here are a couple examples:

```
select employee, 
       sum(case when is_cancelled != 1 then 1 else 0 end) total_orders,
       sum(case when sale_amount < 100 then 1 else 0 end) orders_below_100dollars,
       sum(case when sale_amount >= 100 then 1 else 0 end) orders_above_100dollars,
       ...
from sales
group by employee
```

I'm not exactly sure what constitutes daytime vs nighttime, but it should be easy to add given the above.

Comment: Great minds think alike! These can be shorted to something like `SUM(is_cancelled != 1)` instead of using a case statement in each one.

Comment: @McAdam331 -- yeah, I just find this easier to read and more consistent across different databases.  But I agree, good timing.

Comment: daytime, nighttime is concerned with sale_time

Comment: @sgeddes all cases need to have is_cancelled = 0 in the select